# How to scale tds independently of one another?

Tags: html, css

I have to do this for (part of) an assignment. I personally would never use tables like this, I would always use divs if given the choice, but I have to use tables for the assignment.

Here is a very simplified version of what I need to recreate:
[image]

But here is the best I can do:

[image]

The tds always want to scale with one another. Also, this needs to be done with a single table. I've tried messing around with `rowspan` and such in addition to height but I can't even get close to the desired result. Is there some sort of attribute I'm not aware of that could simplify this type of layout?

My current approach is to have two rows and two columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess would be to use three rows in two columns, and rowspan:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!-- the cell above extends into here -->
        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <!-- the cell above extends into here -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

Getting the heights to work specifically can be a problem, especially on older browsers, but the best way to do that often depends on the content of the cells.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize the rowspan attribute:

Here is a sample:

I have added some height to look more like the picture you attached.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" height="200">1</td>
        <td height="50">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" height="200">B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="50">2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vmm2y/

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution

```
    <table border="1" width="500">
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2" style="height:200px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2" style="height:200px">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

you can use ......class for inline stype

Answer (score 1):

Better than the code solution, I prefer to write down the **algorithm**:

- Every time you can spot an horizontal border in any column, than it's a new row.
- Every time you can spot a vertical border in any row, than it's a new column.
- When it's done, you then have to rowspan/colspan together all the cells that don't have borders.

Done (OK I didn't describe how to merge cells, but it should be easier than a *sudoku* grid ;)

edit: here you've 2 horizontal borders (and the bottom of the table) so 3 rows. 1 vertical border (full height so no `colspan` in your final code) and right border of table: 2 columns.

Comment: Can you really do it without a rowspan? All other solutions rely on it.

Comment: Oops I meant `colspan` and wrote `rowspan` :( No `th`/`td` will occupy 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td rowspan="2">$50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td rowspan="2">$80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$80</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This uses three columns, which is not what I need, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/ekidef/1/edit)**

As you mentioned that you would like to achieve this using `div`'s, I created one.

**HTML**

```
<div id="first">
   <div id="leftTop"></div>
   <div id="leftBot"></div></div>
<div id="second">
   <div id="rightTop"></div>
   <div id="rightBot"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#left,#right{
      float:left;
      width:150px;
      height:300px;
      border:2px solid black;
}
#leftTop{
      height:250px;
      border-bottom:2px solid black;
}
#rightTop{
      height:50px;
      border-bottom:2px solid black;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/ekidef/1/edit)**

Comment: I appreciate the div solution, and my question may have not been clear but I said I would normally use divs but I have to use a table. But thanl you for this soltuion.